# Receive data in Json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am posting data to my script file to receive data. In my script file, `File.php`, I am not able to get the object `patient` in the dumped results. When i do `var_dump($get_patient_info->patient);,` 
it throws an error saying **Object {patient}** not found.

Could i be mapping the data wrongly?

PS: Beginner in Laravel

**SendingData Controller**

```
$hospitalData = [];
$hospitalData[] = [           
            'patient' => 'Mohammed Shammar',
            'number' => '34',
               ],

        $url = "https://example.com/file.php";
        $client = new Client();
        $request = $client->post($url, [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'patient_info',
                    'contents' => json_encode($hospitalData),
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $response = $request->getBody();
        return $response;
```

**File.php**

```
$get_patient_info = $_POST['patient_info'];

          var_dump($get_patient_info);
```

**Results**

```
string(189) "[{"patient":"Mohammed Shammar","number":"34"}]"
```

Comment: `$get_patient_info[0]->patient` ?

Comment: You need to `json_decode` `$get_patient_info` first. Though unsure why you're using multipart and not json.

Comment: @quickSwap i get Trying to get property 'patient' of non-object

Comment: `$temp = json_decode($get_patient_info); echo $get_patient_info[0]->patient` ?

Comment: That's how var_dump gives output, try print_r after json_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can json_decode and fetch the data as follows,

```
$temp = json_decode($get_patient_info); 
echo $get_patient_info[0]->patient;
```

[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) — Decodes a JSON string

Hope this helps.